# How to fix missing dependency warning when using non-existent value as a parameter with useEffect React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using React 17.0.2, I get this error when trying to make universal fetch(snapshot) function

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency 
array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

My code

```
const useSnapshot = (collection, id) => {
...
useEffect(() => {
    ...
        id ? setData([items[id]]) : setData(items);
    });
}, [collection, id]);
return { data, isPending, error };
};
```

As I'm concern the problem is covered in fact that **id** sometimes can be undefined
It's neccessary to get access not only to the list, but also to each element forwarding id.

Please, help me solve this problem

Comment: Do you have something like `eslint` installed? These kind of errors are happening because you probably bootstrapped your project with `create-react-app`. It should highlight in red if you have the eslint plugin.
What if you just add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` right above the hooks dependencies? It should prevent that error from happening